# Highlight if link is selected

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to highlight the currently selected link in a link-bar, whereas the other links that are not selected should stay as they were. My idea is to assign a class within an if-statement (e.g. if the link contains the string "date=3", it will be assigned to class "selected) in order to style it then in CSS. But I dunno how it's done, can you help me please?

My hyperlink within PHP looks this way:

```
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=()/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=3";?>"><?php echo date("l, j F",strtotime($mayday)+60*60*24*3); ?></a>
```

Comment: please provide some more context..

Comment: You want to highlight after each load or dynamically? For the last one, i can recommend jQuery: http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by each load exactly. If link1 is selected, that link1 should by highlighted, whereas link2 and so forth remain as plain text. If you select link2 afterwards, then link2 would be highlighted and link1 and all others would be plain text.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the link will always include date=3 !

But you want to evaluate if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] contains date=3 ?

```
<a'.(preg_match("|date=3|",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? "class=\"selected\"" : "").' href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=()/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=3";?>"><?php echo date("l, j F",strtotime($mayday)+60*60*24*3); ?></a>
```

Comment: I got several links as follows and I want to style the link that is currently selected individually.
`<?php $rasp = $_GET["location"]; ?><?php if(!empty($rasp)) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=0"; ?>">today</a> | <a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=()/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=2"; ?>"><?php echo en_date("l, j F",strtotime($mayday)+60*60*24*2); ?></a> | <a href="<?php echo preg_replace("/&date=()/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])."&date=3";?>"><?php echo en_date("l, j F",strtotime($mayday)+60*60*24*3); ?></a>`

Comment: As I read it, your preg_replace should be preg_replace("/&date=(0|1|2|3)/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) - or maybe /&date=[0-9]+/ - which is more generic - in all links, though?

Comment: Hm this preg_match Expression doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong when calling the class in CSS? `.selected { font-size: 14px; }`